# Rotating hundreds of JPEGs in seconds rather than hours

Tags: opengl, graphics, opencv, opencl, image-rotation

We have hundreds of images which our computer gets at a time and we need to rotate and resize them as fast as possible.
Rotation is done by 90, 180 or 270 degrees.

Currently we are using the command line tool [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) to rotate the image. Rotating the images (5760*3840 ~ 22MP) takes around 4 to 7 seconds.

The following [python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259678/easiest-way-to-transpose-an-image-rotate-by-90-degrees-using-opencv) sadly gives us equal results

```
import cv
img = cv.LoadImage("image.jpg")
timg = cv.CreateImage((img.height,img.width), img.depth, img.channels) # transposed image

# rotate counter-clockwise
cv.Transpose(img,timg)
cv.Flip(timg,timg,flipMode=0)
cv.SaveImage("rotated_counter_clockwise.jpg", timg)
```

Is there a faster way to rotate the images using the power of the graphics card? OpenCL and OpenGL come to mind but we are wondering whether a performance increase would be noticable.

The hardware we are using is fairly limited as the device should be as small as possible.

- [Intel Atom D525 (1,8 Ghz)](http://ark.intel.com/products/49490/)
- [Mobility Radeon HD 5430 Series](http://www.amd.com/de/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-5400/Pages/hd-5430-specs.aspx)
- 4 GB of RAM
- SSD Vertility 3

The software is debian 6 with official (closed source) radeon drivers.

Comment: While reading this question, I wondered to myself: What percentage of the time is spent doing each part of this operation?  How much of the wait is from the JPEG encoding vs. the actual rotation operation?  And how much of the wait is from disk IO?  The answers to those questions might have an impact on your optimizations.

Comment: Just use jpeg tran, which, as a nice side effect, doesn't impair the quality.

Comment: Can you provide timings for each part of the code you pasted (after loading, after transpose, after flip, after save)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can perform a lossless rotation that will just modify the EXIF section. This will rotate your pictures faster.

and have a look at jpegtran utility which performs lossless jpeg modifications.
https://linux.die.net/man/1/jpegtran

Comment: Changing Exif Orientation tag is probably the fastest method. However not all image viewers honor it. `jpegtran` seems like a good solution. It will only partially re-compress your image which should still be pretty fast.

Comment: If the image width/height are multiples of 8 you can rotate 90/180/270deg by simply reordering the components without recompression

Comment: @MartinBeckett: Note that most JPEG images are stored as multiple of 8 dimensions and just apply cropping afterwards, so jpegtran should be able to reorder components for most images.

Answer (score 4):

There is a jpeg no-recompression plugin for [irfanview](http://www.irfanview.ca/) which IIRC can rotate and resize images (in simple ways) without recompressing, it can also run an a directory of images - this should be a lot faster

The GPU probably wouldn't help, you are almost certainly I/O limited in opencv, it's not really optomised for high speed file access

Comment: Here you'll find more utilities that will do this rotation losslessy without uncompressing and compressing image again: http://jpegclub.org/losslessapps.html

Comment: For a large number of images, buffering and/or async memory transfers can alleviate the I/O bottleneck - so I wouldn't say that a GPU-based implementation won't help.

Comment: @ananthonline - if the jpeg is simply rotating multiples of 90 then you just have to reshuffle the compressed values in each 8x8 block. A GPU doesn't really help there and is generaly slow at random memory read/writes, even once you have the data on the card. It may  be faster if you were recompressing, although DCT with SSE2 is very fast

Comment: Well - you DO have to recompress certain blocks because the image size changed, no? And for a large image, even those will benefit from the massive parallelism of the GPU. And decoding + lossy rotate options become feasible when using the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in jpeg and compression topics, but as your problem is pretty much as I/O limited as it gets (assuming that you can rotate without heavy de/encoding-related computation), you you might not be able to accelerate it very much on the GPU you have. (Un)Luckily your reference is a pretty slow Atom CPU.

I assume that the Radeon has separate main memory. This means that data needs to be communicated through PCI-E which is the extra latency compared to CPU execution and without hiding you can be sure that it is the bottleneck. This is the most probable reason why your code that uses OpenCV on the GPU is slow (besides the fact that you do two memory-bound operations, transpose & flip, instead of a single one).

The key thing is to hide as much of the PCI-E transfer times with computation as possible by using [multiple-buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering). Overlapping transfers both to and from the GPU with computation by making use of the full-duplex capability of PCI-E will only work if the card in question has dual-DMA engines like [high-end Radeons](http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/graphics/2010/12/15/ati-radeon-hd-6970-review/1) or the [NVIDIA Quadro/Tesla cards](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/40049/Dual_copy_engines.pdf) -- which I highly doubt.

If your GPU compute-time (the time it takes the GPU to do the rotation) is lower than the time the transfer takes, you won't be able to fully overlap. The HD 4530 has a pretty slow memory interface with only [12.8 Gb/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Mobility_Radeon_HD_5xxx_Series) peak, and the rotation kernel should be quite memory bound. However, I can only guesstimate, but I would say that if you reach peak PCI-E transfer rate of ~1.5 Gb/s (4x PCI-E AFAIK), the compute kernel will be a few times faster than the transfer and you'll be able to overlap very little. 
You can simply time the parts separately without requiring elaborate asynchronous code and you can estimate how fast can you get things with an optimum overlap.

One thing you might want to consider is getting hardware which doesn't exhibit PCI-E as a bottleneck, e.g:

- [AMD APU](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/fusion/Pages/fusion.aspx)-based system. On these platforms you will be able to page-lock the memory and use it directly from the GPU;
- integrated GPUs which share main memory with the host;
- a fast low-power CPU like a mobile Intel Ivy Bridge e.g. [i5-3427U](http://ark.intel.com/products/64903/Intel-Core-i5-3427U-Processor-%283M-Cache-up-to-2_80-GHz%29) which consumes almost as little as the [Atom D525](http://ark.intel.com/products/49490) but has AVX support and should be several times faster.