# Document detection using OpenCv forming performance degradation in Android

Tags: opencv, camera, android-camera, android

I am new to OpenCv with android .I am trying to make an application which auto detects documents using OpenCv - 2.4.13 . In my app, there is a functionality of detection documents (**like Scanbot app**) and then convert it to document. 
So far i am being able to detect documents using opencv in landscape mode.
What i need is showing app in portrait mode . Since, by default OpenCv for android  working in landscape mode, I want it in **portrait mode** . 
I have gone through lots of solutions for that and it worked too but having **performance degradation issues** (like **Camera frame slower down**). 
What i gone through so far is :
  [Rotate camera preview to Portrait Android OpenCV Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816166/rotate-camera-preview-to-portrait-android-opencv-camera)

[Rotating Android Camera to Portrait](http://answers.opencv.org/question/7313/rotating-android-camera-to-portrait/)

However ,i am able to change camera orientation in **portrait but with some performance degradation issues**

**Has anyone done this successfully ?**

I am also looking for **other options to auto detect documents besides  OpenCv**. I don't know whether **it is possible without OpenCv or not**.

**Is it Possible to auto detect documents without OpenCv ? How ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through the same problem with opencv and after hours of research i finally found solution . You have to make changes in default opencv class .
Follow this steps:
1) In CameraBridgeViewBase class add following code

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(90f);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCacheBitmap, 0, 0, mCacheBitmap.getWidth(), mCacheBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

2) now in drawbitmap method replace above **bitmap** with **mCacheBitmap** , as like below

```
if (mScale != 0) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(0,0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()),
                        new Rect((int)((canvas.getWidth() - mScale*bitmap.getWidth()) / 2),
                                (int)((canvas.getHeight() - mScale*bitmap.getHeight()) / 2),
                                (int)((canvas.getWidth() - mScale*bitmap.getWidth()) / 2 + mScale*bitmap.getWidth()),
                                (int)((canvas.getHeight() - mScale*bitmap.getHeight()) / 2 + mScale*bitmap.getHeight())), null);
            } else {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()),
                        new Rect((canvas.getWidth() - bitmap.getWidth()) / 2,
                                (canvas.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight()) / 2,
                                (canvas.getWidth() - bitmap.getWidth()) / 2 + bitmap.getWidth(),
                                (canvas.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight()) / 2 + bitmap.getHeight()), null);
  }
```

3) now , In your **JavaCameraView** class replace following code in **initializeCamera** method (changing height ,width for Portrait mode)

```
if ((getLayoutParams().width == ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) && (getLayoutParams().height == ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
                    mScale = Math.min(((float)height)/mFrameWidth, ((float)width)/mFrameHeight); 
                else
                    mScale = 0;
```

and you are done !!

I don't think , there is any alternative other than OpenCv for auto detection of objects

Comment: Thanks a lot @ImLearning , you made my day

Comment: I am having it too . see this link  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712993/drawcontours-around-detected-document-using-opencv-for-android-gives-strange-bug