# drawContours around detected document using opencv for android gives strange bug

Tags: opencv, contour, edge-detection, android

I am new to OpenCv4Android. I am trying to auto detect document using OpenCv4Android sdk. Initially i have gone through issue of landscape opencv camera . Somehow i managed to change the orientation of opencv JavaCameraview to portrait. I made following changes in default classes of opencv sdk to orient opencv camera in portrait :

1) In **CameraBridgeViewBase** class

```
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 matrix.setRotate(90f);
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCacheBitmap, 0, 0, mCacheBitmap.getWidth(), mCacheBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

2) now in drawbitmap method replace above **bitmap** with **mCacheBitmap**

3) now , In **JavaCameraView** class

```
if ((getLayoutParams().width == ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) && (getLayoutParams().height == ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
       mScale = Math.min(((float)height)/mFrameWidth, ((float)width)/mFrameHeight);
else
       mScale = 0;
```

After above changes , i am able to orient camera in portrait mode . But , having strange issue in detecting document . See below images

[image] [image]

As you can see in first image , before customization i can detect paper in full green color . And in 2nd image you can see the bug of drawing line  (drawContours) around paper

what i follow to detect paper is : **GaussianBlur -> Canny edge detection -> findContours  -> drawContour**

In OnCameraFrame method :

```
     mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
   Mat mGray = new Mat();
   Mat edged = new Mat();       
  Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba,mGray,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mRgba,mGray,new Size(5,5),0);
```

-> and then finding contours

```
Imgproc.findContours(edged, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

-> Then i found the largest contour and finally the drawContours on that

```
Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, maxI, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 5);
```

I don't know where i m wrong..! Please help me to solve this strange issue.

@Rick M.  following is the original image :

[image]

@ilke444 , following is the image after edge detection which is perfectly what i want :
 [image]

Comment: If you visualize your intermediate inputs (after the blur, then edges, then contours), you can see better why the lines with higher angles with horizontal and vertical are problematic. Also, it would help us pinpoint the problem better if you can post your code for those steps.

Comment: @ilke444 , i updated my code please check it out ..

Comment: I don't think the bug is in drawContours as you suggest. Can you post the original image?

Comment: yaah , you are right @RickM. I came to know that the problem is in the first step where i rotate bitmap to 90 degree :

Comment: see this : matrix.setRotate(90f);
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCacheBitmap, 0, 0, mCacheBitmap.getWidth(), mCacheBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

Comment: Can you also share the image after edge detection?

Comment: @ilke444 the result after edge detection is perfectly what i want , the issue is only when i am trying to draw contours around document . I have updated question with image after edge detection , please check

Comment: I'm also stuck in a similar situation. Can I have a look at your code for reference?

Comment: @ImLearning can you please post how you found the largest rectangle with contours..