# Fast image (or matrix) transpose implementation in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259678/easiest-way-to-transpose-an-image-rotate-by-90-degrees-using-opencv) discussed about how to transpose an image with OpenCV, and here I want to go further: suppose the image is gray-scale one, what is the fastest way of transposing it (or matrix) using C++?  My solution is as follows:

```
        // image data is stored in an image buffer image*buffer_

    unsigned char *mem = (unsigned char *) malloc(image.bufferSize_);

    int height = image.Height();
    int width = image.Width();
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        unsigned char *ptr =image.buffer_+i*width;
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
            *(mem+j*height+i) = *(ptr+j);
    }


    memcpy(image.buffer_,mem,image.bufferSize_);
    free(mem);
```

Some explanations above the above code: we create an image object that contains basic image information as well as the image pixels (in `image.buffer_`). When image pixels are stored in `image.buffer_`, we assume the image pixels are kept row by row. Any ideas on further improving the above codes?

Comment: Why are you using `malloc`/`free` when programming C++?

Comment: Why not just use `cvTranspose()` or `cv::transpose()` ?

Comment: why bother ? `Mat m; m.t();` is the transpose

Comment: I agree, you're not going to beat the cv::Mat::t()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without touching the malloc/free part, the copying part could go like this:

```
    size_t len = image.bufferSize_,
           len1 = len - 1;

    unsigned char *src = image.buffer_,
                  *dest = mem,
                  *end = dest + len;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        *dest++ = *src;  // dest moves to next row
        src += height;   // src moves to next column

        // src wraps around and moves to next row
        if (src > end) src -= len1;
    }
```

This is a equivalent to having a column-wise destination iterator and a row-wise source iterator.

Without actually testing it, I feel this will be faster: it has 3 operations for offset computation in the inner loop vs. 4 in your version (plus 2 dereferencing operations in both versions).

**EDIT**

One more improvement, and a correction:

```
    //...
    unsigned char *src = image.buffer_,
                  *src_end = src + len,
                  *dest = mem,
                  *dest_end = dest + len;

    while (dest != dest_end)
    {
        *dest++ = *src;  // dest moves to next row
        src += height;   // src moves to next column

        // src wraps around and moves to next row
        if (src > src_end) src -= len1;
    }
```

This saves one more operation per iteration (`i++` in the `for` loop). Also `src` was compared to the wrong `end` previously.

Comment: it should be if (src >= src_end) src -= len1;