# MATLAB imrotate back to original size and orientation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, image-rotation

I have used `imrotate` function to rotate an image without using the `'crop'` argument and now after some processing I would like to imrotate back to have the original orientation and size. Is there a way to do that, maybe with other functions other than imrotate?

Comment: Use negative of the angle used for `imrotate`?

Comment: not working, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: What are you getting when using another call to `imrotate` with the negative angle?

Comment: do you rotate by angles that are multiples of 90' ?

Comment: the image is now bigger (as I would expect after using imrotate without 'crop' argument). I'd like to have the same (but very same) size as the original. The problem is that imrotate alters the size of the image after rotating to be large enough to contain the entire rotated image.

Comment: no, it's actually something like 332deg.

Comment: @umbe1987 It must have added black borders on all four sides of the final image that you need to crop out based on the sizes of the original image.

Comment: You want to rotate the image back and in such a way that it will be identical to the original image?

Comment: yes, except some modifications I've made to some pixel value. Anyway, I am trying to find out if the image center is still the same to possibly crop myself the image back to the original size.

Comment: What's wrong with simply performing the reverse rotation on the modified pixels **only** and deciding how to antialias the resulting points on the original image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rotation angle is not a multiple of 90' - 0', 90', 180', ... , There is no way to rotate back and get the exact original image. The reason is that the rotation of an image is a non-linear transformation - see in [mathworks-ref-imrotate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html).
The rotation is performed using interpolation, where the default is "nearest".
In your case theta=332' the transformation is non preserving.

So the answer is no.

Note:
For theta = K*90' there is a linear transformation - 2X2 rotation matrix, and also you can use a combination of flip and transpose:
[easiest-way-to-transpose-an-image-rotate-by-90-degrees-using-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259678/easiest-way-to-transpose-an-image-rotate-by-90-degrees-using-opencv)

Comment: Right. The best approximation to obtain a similar (not equal) image as respect the original is then to crop the double-rotated image (with the original orientation) according to the difference between the number of columns and rows between the original image and the processed one and knowing the rotation has been made on the center of the image. Thanks for the clarification.