# correctly rotate or flip images [invoices,forms] to its correct orientation in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, contour

I am trying to rotate the images which contains invoice and forms into its correct orientation . I am trying to find the angle and then rotating the image .few images are getting rotated correctly only .Below is the code and images which i have tried to rotate in correct orientation the first image is rotating correctly and other is rotating incorrect

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
from scipy import ndimage

img_before = cv2.imread('rotate_me.png')

cv2.imshow("Before", img_before)    
key = cv2.waitKey(0)

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_before, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_edges = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 100, 100, apertureSize=3)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img_edges, 1, math.pi / 180.0, 100, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=5)

angles = []

for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(img_before, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 3)
    angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
    angles.append(angle)

median_angle = np.median(angles)
img_rotated = ndimage.rotate(img_before, median_angle)

print "Angle is {}".format(median_angle)
cv2.imwrite('rotated.jpg', img_rotated)
```

first image-[left side inverted] ---after rotation correctly rotating
second image --right side inverted-- wrong rotation 
Both image having -90 degree angle . The final output must be like the image3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpFVy.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGI3k.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHNgD.png

Comment: Currently you are using the line angle this only gives -90 because of a line with angle -90 and a line with angle 90 are the same. This approach does not work for 180-degree rotations. Please describe if your datasets have any logo or some other text in common. Please provide additional information regarding your dataset.

Comment: so @RavitejaNarra most of the data are invoices which can also contain logos.some images are without logo and some images are in the tabular form.Different type of data i have . but the orientation output required as same as the image 3 i have attached

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the lines, I suggest finding the colored area.

If the area is in the right side of the image, the image is needed to be rotated.

Finding the colored area can be done as follows:

- Compute absolute difference between each two color channels, and sum the result.
  The result has high values where there is color (not black/white).
- Apply threshold - values below the threshold will be zero (considered to be black/white), and above threshold will be 255 (colored pixels).
- Find the largest cluster in the threshold image using [connectedComponentsWithStats](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f).
- If the center of the largest white cluster is in the right side, rotate the image.

Here is a code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread("rotate_me1.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

# Compute difference between each two color channels for finding colored pixels.
cdiff = cv2.absdiff(im[:,:,0], im[:,:,1])//3 + cv2.absdiff(im[:,:,0], im[:,:,2])//3 + cv2.absdiff(im[:,:,1], im[:,:,2])//3;
ret, cmask = cv2.threshold(cdiff, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find clusters.
# https://answers.opencv.org/question/194566/removing-noise-using-connected-components/
nlabel,labels,stats,centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(cmask, connectivity=8)

# Find second largest cluster (the largest is the background?):
stats[np.argmax(stats[:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA])] = 0
idx_max_size = np.argmax(stats[:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA])
center = centroids[idx_max_size]

# True if the center of the centroid is at the right side of the image
is_center_at_right_side = center[0] > im.shape[1]//2

if is_center_at_right_side:
    rotated_im = im[::-1, ::-1, :].copy()  # Reverse left/right and up/down
    cv2.imshow('rotated_im', rotated_im)

# Draw green circle at the center (for testing)
cv2.circle(im, (int(center[0]), int(center[1])), 10, (0, 255, 0), thickness=10)

cv2.imshow('cmask', cmask)
cv2.imshow('im', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Example for `cmask`:
[image]

Marking center of largest cluster with green circle:
[image]

Rotated image:
[image]

---

### Update:

Rotate by 90 degree:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259678/easiest-way-to-rotate-by-90-degrees-an-image-using-opencv
if is_center_at_right_side:
    rotated_im = cv2.rotate(im, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
else:
    rotated_im = cv2.rotate(im, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: output which i am looking is like image3 that i have attached (a kind of landscape upper view) not left-right.  
in every case need a output as in image 3

Comment: I added an update to my post. See [Easiest way to rotate by 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259678/easiest-way-to-rotate-by-90-degrees-an-image-using-opencv)

Comment: Hi @rotem thanks for the solution .for these cases its working great but if the image is already in correct form suppose the input image is image3 then why its geting rotated it should be fixed ..please help on this

Comment: The dimensions of the input image are very different in this case (the width is much larger than the height when the orientation is correct). I don't think it's a real challenge checking if the red-blue circle is on the top or bottom, but it makes no sense in the example you have posted.

Comment: Do you really expect me to answer about images I can't see? The answer doesn't address the general case, only the cases you have posted. Don't expect to get a complete working solution as an answer it Stack Overflow site. Treat the answers as a sort of guidance, and help on specific problems.