# c++ image rotation 90 degree

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rotation

I want to read the picture in grayscale and rotate it 90 degrees, but I am making a mistake somewhere. Is there anyone who can help?

```
cv::Mat image = imread(".../jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
cv::resize(image, image,cv::Size(400,400));
cv::Mat imageson;

int rows = image.rows;
int cols = image.cols;


for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rows ; j++)
    {
        imageson.at<uchar>(i,j) = image.at<uchar>(rows-1-j,i);
    }
}

cv::imshow("image",imageson);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

// im beginner btw. output = (exit value:-1)

Comment: _making a mistake_ What sort of mistake?  Compilation error?  Wrong image?  Runtime error?  [Edit] the question to include these details.

Comment: @pero_hero how to get -1 that row value is 400

Comment: sorry weak moment

Comment: Why dont you use [rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259678/easiest-way-to-rotate-by-90-degrees-an-image-using-opencv) function? The reoson of crashing is that the limits are exceeding of the size.

Comment: I want to do without using the rotate function. I want to learn well because I have just started.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I realized there was a problem on limit, but I could not fix it.

Comment: You don't specify size or type of imageson

Comment: @stark I throw the pixels into imageson in the for loop. after all, the original picture is 400x400. Won't there be 400x400 in imagenson?

Comment: Ahh yesss, just initialise the imageson like ```cv::Mat imageson(400, 400, CV_8UC1);```

Comment: @stark && Yunus Temurlenk THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: `cv::rotate(image, image, cv::ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE);`?